# In Razor, problem with Html.Raw() when given an element having a class

Tags: css, razor

In a Razor project I have

```
@{
    string elem="<span class=\"spec\">comment</span>";
}
<div>@Html.Raw(elem)</div>
```

and

```
.spec{
    color: red;
}
```

The color is not applied. Looking in the browser, in debugger, I noticed that I have to write

```
string elem="<span b-skxp0olev1 class=\"spec\">comment</span>";
```

And it works! If I look in the Styles tab, when I apply the magic word I see on top a styling entry like:

```
.spec[b-skxp0olev1] {
    color: red;
}
```

As a matter fact, I came with the described solution observing other elements in the Elements tab of Chrome debugger. For example, I have in my page something as simple as

```
<h6>Version</h6>
```

but I see in the Elements tab something like

```
<h6 b-skxp0olev1>Version</h6>
```

It looks that for most elements, maybe for all, that magic string is automatically added but not in case of Html.Raw() usage.

Another observation: I can write

```
string elem = "<span style=\"font-weight:bold\" class=\"spec\">comment</span>";
```

and the font is bolded even though the magic word is not added by me or by browser. So the problem is with classes and Html.Raw(). When I look in the Styles tab, I see the font-weight but not the spec class.

Analyzing the rest of the elements I see that there are two or three magic words used. Some of the elements use a magic word, other elements some other.

Of course, I don't want to always guess an use such b-skxp0olev1 magic. What to do?

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the described behavior.  The code shown fails to build in my Visual Studio due to a missing semi-colon.  When I correct that, the resulting output is indeed `<span class="spec">comment</span>` as expected.  Can you provide a more complete [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?  And/or additional debugging information about the problem you're observing?

Comment: @David Indeed a semicolon was missing and I corrected the sample code above. Apart from that, on my computer I can reproduce it as it is and the output is just
    comment
but not in red. I have tried again.

Comment: When you examine the page source in the browser, what is the resulting `<span>` element?  In the browser's debugging tools, what style rules are applied to that element?  Since I'm not able to replicate the problem (and I doubt other users will be able to either), we're going to need more debugging information and/or a more complete example.

Comment: @David As the example is small enough I don't know how to simplify it more but I added additional information in the question.

Comment: It sounds like something else is happening outside of what's described in the question.  Because `.spec` and `.spec[b-skxp0olev1]` are very different selectors.  In the original question you indicated that you were using the former, but have since observed that you're actually using the latter.  You'll need to find out why it's different and what is causing it to change.  Whatever is doing that appears to be incompatible with your intent of outputting raw strings as markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that the magic string is the result of a feature called css isolation available in Blazor but now, as it seems, introduced also in Razor. If you use a Visual Studio AspNetCoreMVC project sample this feature is enabled by default. I have also learned that, indeed, @Html.Raw() has a problem with this feature.

The good news is that the magic word can be customized in csproj file.

[ASP.NET Core Blazor CSS isolation - Customize scope identifier format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003978#customize-scope-identifier-format)